# Using sapply to list all parts of a vector, but not show the list on the bottom

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, sapply

I have a bit of code, lets say 
`test<-c("A", "B", "C")` that I want to list individually line by line. I use `sapply(test, FUN=print)` and I get

```
[1] "A"
[1] "B"
[1] "C"
  A   B   C
"A" "B" "C"
```

but I want to get this instead. Is there any way to do so using any of the apply functions?

```
[1] "A"
[1] "B"
[1] "C"
```

I have been able to do this using a for loop

```
for (i in 1:length(test)){
      print(test[i])
}
```

but I'm trying to do this with the apply family specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `invisible` to wrap to that it won't print the output from `sapply`

```
invisible(sapply(test, FUN=print))
#[1] "A"
#[1] "B"
#[1] "C"
```

Comment: Thats it! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

here is a different approach

```
cat(paste0(test,collapse="\n"))

A
B
C
```

Comment: That does work well, and I didn't think of it. But I needed to use apply due to restrictions of others. Thanks though. I'll remember this method.